# Android - Kotlin - setOnClickListener

Tags: android, kotlin

//Good afternoon, I can not find the error in the code, I'm beginner someone could help me?//
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityLoginBinding


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

    // error message if the user does not fill in the email and password fields//

    binding.edit_text_user_email
    binding.edit_text_user_senha

    bt_entrar.setOnClickListener {
        val email = edit_text_user_email.text.toString().trim()
        val senha = edit_text_user_senha.text.toString().trim()


        if (email.isEmpty()) {
            edit_text_user_email.error = "Preencha o Campo Email!"
            edit_text_user_email.requestFocus()
            return@setOnClickListener
        }

        if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            edit_text_user_email.error = "Email Invalido!"
            edit_text_user_email.requestFocus()
            return@setOnClickListener
        }
        if (senha.isEmpty() || senha.length < 6) {
            edit_text_user_senha.error = "Preencha o Campo Senha Max 6 Caracteres!"
            edit_text_user_senha.requestFocus()
            return@setOnClickListener
        }
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------//
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUc3F.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9IjL.png)

Comment: Post the code as text in a code block, not as images, thanks!

Comment: If you can't find the error in your code, it would be helpful to explain what the error is. (Compile error? Logic error? Crash?) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using XML for views, since you have "binding".

To access views, you need to do it through the binding, for example:

```
binding.edit_text_user_email
```

Also, you don't need to use

```
findViewById(R.id.bt_entrar)
```

This button (if it exists in your XML), can be accessed as

```
binding.btEntrar
```

Finally, might I suggest you go over the fundamentals of android development, by visiting some of Google's code labs. For example this one, which uses the new compose framework, over the views framework:
https://developer.android.com/courses/android-basics-compose/course

Or if you are set on using views (XML):
https://developer.android.com/courses/android-basics-kotlin/course

Comment: first thanks for replying! I put more does not pull the button id! I updated the photo so you see since i thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can read more about View Binding [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding).

---

In brief, you need to add the following in your **build.gradle**:

```xml
android {
    ...

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    ...
}
```

Then if you have a layout xml named as **activity_login.xml**, you should have an automatically generated class `ActivityLoginBinding`. In general, **aaa_bbb.xml** should have a generated class `AaaBbbBinding`. And I think you should be doing this correctly.

And you should initialize your `binding` and retrieve your view elements as follow:

```kotlin
private lateinit var binding: ActivityLoginBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // You should initialize layout binding like this
    binding = ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    // Then you can continue getting the view through binding.<view element ID>
    // Set the OnClickListener of button bt_entrar
    binding.bt_entrar.setOnClickListener {
        val email = binding.edit_text_user_email.text.toString().trim()
        val senha = binding.edit_text_user_senha.text.toString().trim()
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: yes I have a layout activity_login xml! and also in app I had already added buildFeatures { true viewBinding what's going on is he doesn't want to recover the ID! I'll put the code below to see setContentView(binding.root) plus I think I've done it, I'll try here !

Comment: Good evening, you can find out! i when I put the binding code = ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) setContentView(binding.root) downstairs to go to the registration page if the user didn't have an account! and up there was setContentView(R.layout.activity_login) deleted this ! and i put it on top binding = ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) setContentView(binding.root) And I also blacked out binding.edit_text_user_email binding.edit_text_user_senha there was it worked thank you all ! @Enowneb also studied the link you sent me thank you very much!

Comment: The code worked! I delete binding.edit_text_user_email binding.edit_text_user_senha setContentView(R.layout.activity_login) and put it in place! binding = ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) setContentView(binding.root), only I had unintentionally duplicated the code down there so I could go to another sign-up window when the user has no account! that was my mistake !